# function calculate the right week number of year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, week-number

I am looking for function that give me the right `week-number`.

The first day of the year should always be on week number 1.
The first saturday of a year belongs to the first week.

In another words: [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14858473/1216680) what i am looking for, but not in `PostgreSQL`, but in `sql-server`.

I realy want to do that using a function that i will call later.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [What, exactly, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Don't bother writing a function. Instead, create a [calendar table](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) and populate it in advance. This is much simpler to maintain and use in queries, and has many other uses too. You may also want to review the [many existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql-server+week+number) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server there's no need for a custom function; just use the built in [`DATEPART` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) with  `week` as the first argument:

```
-- first day
select datepart(week, '2013-01-01');
```

Output: 1

```
-- first Saturday
select datepart(week, '2013-01-05');
```

Output: 1

```
-- first Sunday
select datepart(week, '2013-01-06');
```

Output: 2

```
-- today
select datepart(week, '2013-04-01');
```

Output: 14

Here's a live demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11802

Comment: I don't have same outputs like you, for example: select datepart(week, '2013-01-06'); gives me 1, and select datepart(week, '2013-01-07'); gives me 2

Comment: @Houari that may be because of your [`DATEFIRST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) setting

Comment: And wheni run select @@datefirst on my server, i get 1, but in the livedemo i get 7

Comment: @Houari exactly, that's why

Comment: @Houari use `SET DATEFIRST n` (where `n` is the new setting). Also, see the link I provided 4 comments above

Comment: But i can't do the set `datefirst` inside a function, and as i need to get it using a function

Answer (score 0):

select datepart(week, getdate()) as CurrentWeekofYear